# html pattern for at least 5 characters but no leading or trailing whitespaces

Tags: regex, html

For the security reasons  I want to limit the password to at least 5 characters(letters of any language, numbers, punctuation,special_charavters ) in an HTML form using pattern attribute
but I also want to disallow leading or trailing whitespaces while allowing whitespaces in between words. So `length(trim(password)>=5)` will be true.
so the correct password would be for example

```
abc1245
abc12
1 34~_
1             34~_
спасибо Россия
```

and  incorrect ones  will be for example

```
a sd 
 123 __
```

I've tried to use this pattern

```
^\b[/S ]{5,}*\b$
```

but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It contains leading & trailing spaces.

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172045/3832970) worked for you. If you found it helpful, please also consider upvoting (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

```
pattern="\S(?:\s*\S){3}.*\S"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uRw3da/1)

It will be compiled as `^(?:\S(?:\s*\S){3}.*\S)$` pattern that matches

- `^(?:` - start of string and opening of the non-capturing group
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `(?:\s*\S){3}` - 3 repetitions of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `)$` - end of the non-capturing group and the end of string anchor added by HTML5 engine.

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="\S(?:\s*\S){3}.*\S" title="Please enter at least 5 non-whitespace chars, no leading/trailing whitespace allowed!" value=" abc __   " />
 <input type="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

**Note**: [HTML5 pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) value is anchored by default, i.e. the whole pattern is wrpapped into `^(?:` and `)$`. You do not have to put `^` and `$` between the pattern, and even if you add an alternative as Jan did, you do not need the `^`/`$` around the empty value.

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

Comment: I ended up increasing the number of password characters to 6. I marked this answer as correct one because it's the most complete one. thanks for the explanation @WiktorStribizew

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`<input type="text" required pattern="[^\s].{3,}[^\s]" name='foo'>`

This will disallow any first or last to be `\s` (white space). In between needs 3 (or more) of anything which sums up to 5 chars in total.

Note that a password containing 5 chars is still very small and can easily be brute forced. Especially if someone got the database or if you have no brute force protection on your server.

The pattern attribute does not need start `^` and end `$` markers.

Comment: You need the pattern `^[^\s].{3,}[^\s]$`. You forgot the `^` and `$`. Those are neccessary. Test here: https://regex101.com/r/uQSawx/1

Comment: @HerrSerker No, `^` and `$` are already added by the HTML5 engine when compiling the regex object.

Comment: @HerrSerker, that's a difference between JavaScript(and other) regex and the HTML pattern attribute. Question is about the latter. Also what I meant with the last sentence in my answer. (edited it to make it clear)

Comment: @René That I didn't knew. But you seem to be correct

Comment: Here's the MDN reference on the pattern attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern It says: "The pattern must match the entire value."

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `\S.{5,}\S`:

```
<input required pattern="\S.{3,}\S" title="Please match the format.">
```